# Vuejs screwing up the selected option in a select component

Tags: binding, vuejs2

I think it is a bug!
I couldn't replicate this issue in fiddle.

I'm passing data from parent to child component in order to select a default option in a select element. This select, which is in the child component, is populated by the child component itself and the default value should come from the parent.

So, once everything renders the select is not marked the default option according to the parent value, also, the parent value is being deleted.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <h1></h1>

    <h4>Example 1</h4>
    <user :account="account"></user>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import user from './User.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',

  components: {user},

  created() {
    this.getAccount();
  },

  data () {
    return {
      account: {
        id: '',
        name: ''
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getAccount() {
      this.$http.get('account.json')
      .then((res) => {
        this.account.id = res.body.id
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

User.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ account }}<br>
    <select v-model="account.id">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option v-for="(user, index) in users" :value="user.id">{{ user.name }}</option>
  </select>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    account: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.getUsers();
  },

  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getUsers() {
      this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then((res) => {
        this.users = res.body;
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I made a package using https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack in order to facilitate your help. You can download the package [here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/obvex1)

Comment: A better way to share your working code can be sharing a [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mimani/ajy0e03c/1/).

Comment: I couldn't represent the issue in fiddle, sorry!

Comment: Solution is here https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4897